# Extension of the the single-fermion tight-binding model to multiple-fermions clusters

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, group-theory, second-quantization, tight-binding

The tight-binding model describes the properties of tightly bound single fermions crystals. Has the model been extended to multiple tightly bound fermions per site? In other words, I'm interested in studying a *cluster* of fermions in which onsite interactions play an important role, but intercluster interactions are weak. I would then like to create a crystal whose repeating periodic sites are the clusters. The difficulty will be to include inter-cluster hopping.

I would be grateful for any suggested papers describing such a many-fermion cluster tight-binding model (preferably in second quantisation, not the scourge that is first-quantisation!) or any suggestions as to how to proceed deriving such a theory myself. Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you are asking about the Hubbard model. You will want to check out Auerbach's *Interacting Electrons and Quantum Magnetism*. Fradkin's book is also a good resource.

Comment: The Hubbard model describes a cluster. My question is how to create a generalisation of a Bloch wave, with the single-fermion sites generalised to many-electron clusters.

Comment: I guess I am confused about how you are using the word cluster. In my mind, each lattice sites in the Hubbard model can act as a cluster. If there is some internal degree of freedom (spin, flavor, whatever), there can be multiple fermions in each cluster, and the fermions within each cluster can interact. I'm not clear how this is different from what you are talking about.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm grateful. I see now that you're right and that the Hubbard model is sufficient.